# How can I call the variables of type map in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am unable to call variables that have been defined as a map. I am getting an error "Invalid Reference". Below is my code sample:

#### File *main.tf*

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "beta" {
aliases                        = [
    "${var.env[0]}.${var.project_name}.${var.domain_name}",
]
comment                        = var.comment[0]
default_root_object            = var.default_root_object
enabled                        = var.enabled
http_version                   = var.http_version
is_ipv6_enabled                = var.is_ipv6_enabled
```

#### File *variables.tf*

```
variable "env" {
     default = ["beta", "luna", "mars", "lab", "test", "sandbox", "preprod"]
}

# Variables for CloudFront
variable "comment" {
    default = ["CloudFront distribution for: beta",
               "CloudFront distribution for: luna",
               "CloudFront distribution for: mars",
               "CloudFront distribution for: lab",
               "CloudFront distribution for: test",
               "CloudFront distribution for: sandbox",
               "CloudFront distribution for: preprod" ]

}
```

Comment: Neither of the two variables is a map. Please add a reproducible blocks of code along with the full error message to the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In Terraform, you can define a variable of type map and access its values using syntax similar to most programming languages.

Here's an example of how you can define and use map variables in Terraform:

```
variable "user_details" {
  description = "A map of user details"
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    name  = "John Doe"
    email = "johndoe@example.com"
    role  = "Administrator"
  }
}

output "user_name" {
  description = "Display the name from the user details map"
  value = var.user_details["name"]
}

output "user_email" {
  description = "Display the email from the user details map"
  value = var.user_details["email"]
}

output "user_role" {
  description = "Display the role from the user details map"
  value = var.user_details["role"]
}
```

In this example, user_details is a map that contains details about a user. You can access the values in the map using the syntax var.user_details[""], where  is the key you want to access in the map.

When you run terraform apply, you'll see the values of the map printed out:

```
user_name = "John Doe"
user_email = "johndoe@example.com"
user_role = "Administrator"
```

This is a simple way to use map variables in Terraform. Keep in mind that all keys and values in a map must be of the same type. If you want to have different types in your map, you can use the object type instead.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT